# How to validate DataGridViewTextBoxColumn in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am new to Windows Desktop Application Development.

I am using a grid view of type DataGridViewTextBoxColumn in which user is allowed to input the data. There are two columns in grid view Qty & Rate in which user should not enter the values other than numbers.

I want to validate those two columns. How do I achieve this.?

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The CellValidating event handler is where you determine whether the value of a cell in the Qty and Rate column is not integer. If the cell value fails validation, set the Cancel property of the DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs class to true.

Comment: How can I determine the column is Qty column or Amount column in `CellValidating` event @Anand Vyas

Comment: you can use Int32.Parse on it and if it throws exception it is not an integer.

Comment: You can set these changes in the designer of the datagridview. You can set their data type and only allow certain types